# Can you schedule a cron that starts at a specific minute and hour and repeats?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

For example, I'd like it to trigger at 6:30, 6:40, 6:50, 7:00, 7:10, 7:20..etc

Is it possible to schedule a cron job that starts at 6:30 every day and runs every 10 minutes until 10:00?

I've tried (30/10 6-10 ? * * * *), but that triggers 6:30, 6:40, 6:50, 7:30, 7:40 and misses the triggers between 7 and 7:30

This is on AWS EventBridge's scheduler.

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score 0):

With 30/10 it will start after 30 mins for every 10 mins. Due to this for every hour it will miss the 0-30 mins window

Why not try 0/10 6-10 ? * * *

Starting 3 - 6.00 6.10 & 6.20 will be extra but it works for other times

[image]

Comment: Because it's for sending out notifications for work to do.  The shifts don't start till 6:30, so I can't send them out before them without everyone getting annoyed.  I worked it out another way, I was a little surprised I wasn't able to do this in cron.